# Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:4200, *', but only one is allowed

Tags: asp.net, angular, cors

I use angular on the front end and .net5 on te backend. I deploy my backend to ubuntu 20.04 server and run it with nginx.
I faced this issue while attempt to login. My get functions works well but login(post) is not.
I searched hours and hours and add `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;` to my `etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file.
But nothing changes. Do you have any idea?

Comment: What does your CORS config look like in the .NET code?

Answer (score 0):

Does your .NET backend allows CORS
e.g
have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Also while you are modifying NGINX conf make sure to restart the service.
e.g
sudo systemctl restart nginx